# How do i reference something in an array that the user has created

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

At the start of the code the user determines a number of keywords and the keyword strings themselves, they place this into an array. Lets say the user says 3 keywords and they are "music", "sports" and "memes". After all this, say the user inputs in the program "I like sports". I simply want the program to respond with "Let's talk about sports" after recognising that the user said sports which is in the array that the user has essentially created.

I want to reference a string the user has predetermined then print it along with a message

I can see the potential of this working using for loops and going through every article until you find a match, I haven't done much work with booleans yet so I just need some assistance punching out the code then learning from it

this all has to happen inside a while loop so when that's done they can use a different keyword and get the same boring response

thanks

note: I don't actually have any of this code I want in my program yet, this code is just to show you kind of how it fits into the greater scheme of things.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Assignment1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String kwArray[];
            String UserMessage;
            String Target = "";
            int numKw = 0;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("How many keywords do you want?");
            numKw = input.nextInt();
            kwArray = new String[numKw];
            System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());
            input.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < numKw; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter keyword " + (i + 1) + ": ");
                kwArray[i] = input.nextLine();// Read another string
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numKw; i++) {
                kwArray[i] = kwArray[i].toLowerCase();
            }
            int x = 0;
            while (x == 0) {
                System.out.println("Hey I'm a chatbot! Why don't you say something to me!");
                System.out.println("These are the keywords you gave me");
                for (String i : kwArray) {
                    System.out.print(i);
                    System.out.print(", ");
                }
                System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());
                System.out.println("Or you can terminate the program by typing goodbye");
                UserMessage = input.nextLine();
                // Gives the user opportunity to type in their desired message
                UserMessage = UserMessage.toLowerCase();
                if (UserMessage.contains("?")) {
                    System.out.println("I will be asking the questions!");
                }

                if (UserMessage.contains("goodbye")) {
                    x = 1;
                }
            }
            input.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not clear with your intent, i do not see any code that accepts user input after keywords are entered. I guess you want to know if user entered  input contains keyword given earlier or not?

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting the question right, you want to check whether an element exists in the submitted keywords and want to reference it back if you further processing.

For this, instead of an array you could use a HashSet which can check the existence any element in O(1).

Updated the code, but I still feel your query is the same what I understood, putting the exact example of your use case below:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

int keywords = input.nextInt();

for (int i=0; i<keywords; i++) {
    //add to set set like:
    set.add(input.readLine());
}

String userComment = input.readLine();
String[] userCommentWords = userComment.split(" ");

//you can iterate over the words in comment and check it in the set
for (int i=0; i<userCommentWords.length; i++) {
    String word = userCommentWords[i];
    if (set.contains(word)) {
        System.out.println("Let's talk about "+word);
    }
}
```